# PHP - Checkbox issues when trying to get their values

Tags: php, forms, button, checkbox, isset

So I made this simple example to try and get someone to explain to me a problem that I can't understand.

The scenario is this, I have 5 checkboxes in one form and a button in another form. I know I could have created the button in the same form as the checkboxes, but for sake of the example, let's say they absolutely HAVE to be in different forms. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        if(isset($_POST['selecao'])){
            print_r($_POST['selecao']);
        }
    }
$names = array("João", "Ana", "Alex", "Carla", "Carolina");
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
        $limite = 5;
        for($i=0 ; $i<$limite ; $i++){
            ?><input type="checkbox"
                name="selecao[]"
                value="<?php echo $names[$i]?>"/>
                <?php
        }
    ?>  

</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

With the code like this, "print_r($_POST['selecao'])" won't even be executed, however, if I have the button created in the same form as the checkboxes print_r will show the array correctly.

**My question is, how can I get this to work using  different forms, is it even possible?**
Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: If you can use JS you can get it to copy the values into hidden form elements in the second form or using AJAX. I don't think this is possible any other way!

Comment: Can you copy and paste generated HTML code too?

Comment: Wthout JavaScript the button submits only the form it is contained in. I.e., if the button is contained in form B, it only submits the fields and values from form B, while the values from form A also present on that page are not submitted. Easy like this.

Comment: I can use javascript, not really my area of expertise though. Guess I should start looking for some tutorials.

Comment: do you need this check `$_POST['submit2']`

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense then. Thanks for shining a light on this @shadyyx

Answer (score 0):

You have double `<form>` tags, and like that you submit or button or checkboxes. If you want them to submit together, you should begin `<form>` before checkboxes, and end `</form>` after the submit, like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        if(isset($_POST['selecao'])){
            print_r($_POST['selecao']);
        }
    }
$names = array("João", "Ana", "Alex", "Carla", "Carolina");
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
        $limite = 5;
        for($i=0 ; $i<$limite ; $i++){
            ?><input type="checkbox"
                name="selecao[]"
                value="<?php echo $names[$i]?>"/>
                <?php
        }
    ?>  

    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: I know it will work like that. But like I said in my question, I absolutely HAVE to have them in different forms tags. And apparently that is only done using JS. Thanks for replying though :)

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, I did not read the question well. Maybe you understood wrong, why do you have to have them in separate forms?

Comment: This is just an example of a problem I'm having in a bigger project that requires them to be in different forms, didn't want to spam it all over here since it's a little bit confidencial aswell, hence this "dumbed-down" example.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe the second form does not have to be submitted after all, but that depends on the project. You can try something like `onSubmit="return !document.forms[0].submit()"` on the `<form>` tag of the second form, so when you submit the second one, you will actually submit the first.